# How to save a data after user logs in DJANGO

Tags: python, django, forms, django-login

After user logs in, user is able to submit a form.  On click of submit button, data is being stored in DB, but how should I connect this information to the submitting user.

I would need the code as well as the structure of the new db

Kind of starting out in django.
Any help would be appreciated!!!

I have included user as foreign key in the `CustomizeRequest` model, but now how do i fill in this information?

**Exact Scenario**: After user log in, once he comes to `contactUs.html`, he submits a form which tells the number of travellers. This number is being stored in the DB. But now how do I connect each of these numbers to the submitted user?

**models.py**

```
class CustomizeRequest(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    travellers = models.CharField(max_length=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.travellers
```

**contactUs.html**

```
<form method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
{% for radio in crform.travellers %}
    <label class="btn btn-default {% if radio.choice_label = '1'   %}active{% endif %}" for="{{ radio.id_for_label }}">
      {{ radio.choice_label }}
      {{ radio.tag }}
    </label>
{% endfor %}
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-warning">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

**views.py**

```
def contactUs(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        form = CustomizeRequestForm(request.POST)
        form.save()
    else:
        form = CustomizeRequestForm()
    context_dict = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'tour/contactUs.html', context_dict)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on catavaran answer (with a check to see if the form is valid):

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render

@login_required
def contactUs(request):    
    form = CustomizeRequestForm(data=request.POST or None)

    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
             customize_request = form.save(commit=False)
             customize_request.user = request.user
             customize_request.save()
             return redirect('.')
        else:
             pass # could add a notification here

    context_dict = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'tour/contactUs.html', context_dict)
```

Comment: so is this the proper way to relate all the inputs given by that user to that specific user

Answer (score 0):

Logged user is available as [`request.user`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user) property.  You can get the unsaved model instance using [form.save(commit=False)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) trick, set the `user` field and then save the instance to database:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render

@login_required
def contactUs(request):    
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CustomizeRequestForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            customize_request = form.save(commit=False)
            customize_request.user = request.user
            customize_request.save()
            return redirect('.')
    else:
        form = CustomizeRequestForm()
    context_dict = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'tour/contactUs.html', context_dict)
```

Comment: at 'customize_request = form.save(commit=False) '  i am getting an error:
   **The CustomizeRequest could not be created because the data didn't            validate.**

Comment: I forget about `is_valid()` call. Sorry.  And show the code of the `CustomizeRequestForm` class.  I suspect that your html template may be invalid.

Comment: in CustomizeRequestForm i had to mention `fields = ("travellers",)` as there were "travellers" and "user" field in the model. i did this and problem seem to be solved